# Add html tag to a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to add a html tag to a string for styling purpose

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("abc", "www.http://stackoverflow.com");
blogList.Items.Add(item);
```

I want to add  tag to string "abc". I looked into HtmlString and HtmlStringWriter but
they look too complicated.

Can anyone demonstrate a small piece of working code? or any method I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a specific css attribute you can use:

```
yourobject.Attributes.Add("background-color", "black");
```

to add a css style already defined in your style sheet you can use:

```
yourobject.CssClass = "classname";
```

I'm not sure why you want HTML within a list item's text, as it seems problematic as Gilbert pointed out, but if you just want to dynamically add HTML to your page there are many ways, including using a Label or a Literal. Simply declare an `<asp:Literal ID="myLit"..>` object on your .aspx page, then within your code source (.cs) file say `myLit.Text = "<p>Some HTML</p>";`

Answer (score 0):

You can't add html tags in a list item object.

You should use a repeater control instead

Comment: ~_~ knew it
but I have no experience with repeater

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx)

```
markup        
<asp:Literal ID="myLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  

codebehind    
myLiteral.Text = "<a href='default.aspx'><b>tag here</b></a>";
```